# How to replace Category Name with Category custom attribute in breadcrumbs Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I want to replace the category name with the category custom attribute in the breadcrumbs on the list and product details page.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have done this. I have posted the answer here because If anyone has the same requirement then use it.
Edit below file path:
**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml**

In my case My custom custom attribute code is **category_seo_name**.
So this code according above attribute code, you can change this as per your code.

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbName ?>">
            <?php
            /* ---- Replace Category Name with Custom attribute category_seo_name ---- */
            $catStr = strtolower($crumbName);
            if (strpos($catStr, 'category') !== false) {
                $categoryId = trim((int) filter_var($catStr, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
                if($categoryId) {
                    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
                    $catSeoName = trim($category->getCategorySeoName());
                    if($catSeoName) {
                        $crumbInfo['label'] = $catSeoName;
                    }
                }
            }
            /* ---------------- */
            ?>
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```